# Web app: something wrong with paths?

Tags: css, jsp, web, web.xml, web-inf

For some reasons it seems my web app has something wrong with paths.

I've the following path for my WEB-INF in Eclipse:

```
Project
   --src
     -- main
        --webapp
          --WEB-INF
             --jsp
             --css
```

I created a project using Spring, Hibernate and Maven.

But this for example doesn't work and doesn't load the styles from my jsp pages:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The welcome page and the error page into the web.xml do not work too:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/students</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The result for an error page is the message "The website cannot display the page" into the browser. However if I remove the error-page configuration I get a stacktrace, so it means that in some way my configuration is used, but something is wrong in interpreting paths.

What may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The welcome file is wrong. It is not a full path but the name of a file to look for in a directory if a directory is requested.

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the error page. Check the WAR/directory that is generated by Eclipse for the applciation to see if the error page is in the right place. Another thing to do is use a static file for the error page until you get it working to rule out any issues with the JSP.